# Select query group by alias

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, resultset

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE AREA_CODE IN ('929', '718', '347', '646') GROUP BY AREA_CODE
```

Is it possible to get only one record row with name 'NEW_YORK_AREA' that includes all these four area codes? To be more clear, let's say you have 4 records in the table for each area code listed above but you want to get only one result(row) with alias 'NEW_YOUR_AREA'. I hope it is clear, let me know if you have any questions, I will edit the question. Thank you all and have a great day.

UPDATE: requirements have changed and it is no longer needed. Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: Please post the structure of table1 as well as the output you wish to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

DB2 supports `listagg()`.  So:

```
SELECT 'NEW_YORK_AREA' as cityname,
       LISTAGG(AREA_CODE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AREA_CODE) as areacodes
FROM TABLE1
WHERE AREA_CODE IN ('212', '929', '718', '347', '646') ;
```

I helpfully added `212`, the most famous NYC area code ;)

If you have duplicates, then you need to use a subquery to remove them before aggregating.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, what you want to do is group everything into the same category.  You could do this by explicitly grouping all rows by a single value:

```
select 'NEW_YORK_AREA',
       --whatever functions you need to aggregate the data here.
       count(var1),
       max(var2)
  from table1
  where area_code in ('929', '718', '347', '646')
  group by 1
```

However, if the only functions that refer to the data in the table are aggregate functions, DB2 lets you omit the `group by`, and it will automatically group everything into a single row.  The following is equivalent to the above query:

```
select 'NEW_YORK_AREA',
       count(var1),
       max(var2)
  from table1
  where area_code in ('929', '718', '347', '646')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a `AREA_CODE_GROUP` table

```
AREA_GROUP,AREA_CODE
'NEW_YORK_AREA','929'
'NEW_YORK_AREA','718'
'NEW_YORK_AREA','347'
'NEW_YORK_AREA','646'
```

that you can join:

```
SELECT t.* FROM TABLE1 "t"
INNER JOIN AREA_CODE_GROUP "g"
ON t.AREA_CODE = g.AREA_CODE
WHERE AREA_GROUP = 'NEW_YORK_AREA'
```